# Wordpress RSS Feed in page builder

Tags: wordpress, widget, rss, siteorigin

i want to create RSS feed, but error occur

> An error has occurred, which probably means the feed is down. Try again later.

i using page builder [page builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/siteorigin-panels/)

this is i used feed url[feed url](https://www.fivesenses.com.au/feed/)

Answer (score 1):

> sudo apt-get install php-xml
>
> sudo service apache2 restart